# wxPython + subprocess. ProgressDialog doesn't work under windows

Tags: windows, multithreading, user-interface, wxpython, subprocess

I have a GUI application which launches some commands using subprocess and then shows the progress of this commands by reading from subprocess.Popen.stdout and using wx.ProgressDialog. I've written the app under Linux and it works flawlessly there, but I'm now doing some testing under windows and it seems that trying to update the progress dialog causes the app to hang. There are no error messages or anything, so it's difficult for me to figure out what's happening. Below is a simplified code:

The subprocess is launched in separate thread by this method in main thread:

```
def onOk(self,event):        
    """ Starts processing """
    self.infotxt.Clear()
    args = self.getArgs()
    self.stringholder = args['outfile']                

    if (args):                       
        cmd = self.buildCmd(args, True)

        if (cmd):
            # Make sure the output directory is writable.
            if not self.isWritable(args['outfile']):
                print "Cannot write to %s. Make sure you have write permission or select a different output directory." %os.path.dirname(args['outfile'])
            else:                
                try:
                    self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.runCmd,args=(cmd,))
                    self.thread.setDaemon(True)
                    self.thread.start()                    
                except Exception:
                    sys.stderr.write('Error starting thread')
```

And here's the runCmd method:

```
def runCmd(self, cmd):
    """ Runs a command line provided as a list of arguments """
    temp = []
    aborted = False
    dlg = None        
    for i in cmd:
        temp.extend(i.split(' '))

    # Use wx.MutexGuiEnter()/MutexGuiLeave() for anything that accesses GUI from another thread                       
    wx.MutexGuiEnter() 
    max = 100
    stl = wx.PD_CAN_ABORT | wx.PD_APP_MODAL | wx.PD_ELAPSED_TIME | wx.PD_REMAINING_TIME
    dlg = wx.ProgressDialog("Please wait", "Processing...", maximum = max, parent = self.frame, style=stl)                               
    wx.MutexGuiLeave()             

    # This is for windows to not display the black command line window when executing the command
    if os.name == 'nt':
        si = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
        si.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
        si.wShowWindow = subprocess.SW_HIDE
    else:
        si = None        

    try:
        proc = subprocess.Popen(temp, shell=False, bufsize=1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)            
    except Exception:
        sys.stderr.write('Error executing a command. ')           

    # Progress dialog    
    count = 0

    while True: 
        line=proc.stdout.readline()
        count += 1           

        wx.MutexGuiEnter()
        if dlg.Update(count) == (True, False):
            print line.rstrip()
            wx.MutexGuiLeave()
            if not line: break
        else:
            print "Processing cancelled."
            aborted = True
            wx.MutexGuiLeave()
            proc.kill()
            break 

    wx.MutexGuiEnter()
    dlg.Destroy()
    wx.GetApp().GetTopWindow().Raise()           
    wx.MutexGuiLeave() 

    if aborted:            
        if os.path.exists(self.stringholder):
            os.remove(self.stringholder)

    dlg.Destroy()
    proc.wait()
```

Again this works fine under Linux, but freezes on Windows. If I remove dlg.Update() line it also works fine. The subprocess output is printed out in main window and ProgressDialog is shown, just progressbar doesn't move. What am I missing?

Comment: It would be great if you can narrow your problem to very small runnable application which we can actually try on our computers.

Comment: I'll try to do it later if I can't find the solution, however you may need some simple C app to test it. The commands I'm executing in subprocess have been modified to avoid any buffering, so proc.stdout.readline() get the output as soon as it's produced. Otherwise the output is unavailable until the command has finished, due to C stdout implementation, which uses full buffering when writing to a pipe. This can be solved on linux using 'unbuffer', but on windows needs some modifications to the C code. I'll get back later if I can't solve the problem using wx.CallAfter.

Answer (score 0):

Try not using `wx.MutexGuiEnter` and `wx.MutexGuiLeave`. You can handle updating the GUI from another thread using `wx.CallAfter`. I have never seen anyone using those mutexes in wx application before and not even in tutorials or examples of using threads.

Comment: Thanks, it's something I'm looking into at the moment.

Comment: OK. BTW there is convenience module for creating new events `wx.lib.newevent`. My be handy in your case...